# How to change columns in a plot with shortcuts

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I am working on Microsoft Excel 2013 scatter plots and I'd like to know if there is a more productive way to do this:
Let's say I have a big database with several columns and rows, i.e:

```
       A      B       C      D
 1   Length  Width  Volume  Area
 2     2      1       8      4
 3     3      2       7      1
 4     1      5       3      5
 5     7      3       12     6
```

I create a scatter plot for Volume vs Length. After, I want to create another scatter plot for Area vs Width. As I have a lot of rows and columns, I copy the first plot and then, in select data, I change the range of data (A to B and C to D). Is there an efficient way to do this? (shortcuts with arrows keys, maybe? I didn't find them) or Do I have to change the letters manually?

Thank you.
J.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a repetitive task in the sense that every say Friday you create the same 4 graphs based on new information in the same columns then you could record a macro of what you are doing and associate it with keyboard short cuts.

You can do the same thing with updating the graph information but it starts getting a little more complex when you start changing which column number you want as the series. But its definitely possible.  I would recommend recording a macro of you editing the 2-3 graphs so we can sheet patterns and we can probably help you edit the macro.

Now something simpler that may, and I stress may, suit your needs.  Select A1 to D5, then insert you XY scatter plot.  You X axis which should be common to all needs to be in the left most column. When you go to edit your source data you should see each series listed.  You can simply check and uncheck which series you would like to have active.  the ones with a check mark will display.  If you needed three graphs at the same time, you could then copy and paste the graphs twice and set up each one to your desire without having to reselect the data range, you would just check/uncheck which series to display